# Huge SQL Statement Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, query-optimization

the following statement is running 11 to 12 seconds per query. I tried to add indicies and other stuff but right now I'm clueless what I should do next.

It's a "search" in codeigniter.

```
   SELECT produktlisten.id as id,
          produktlisten.name as name,
          produktlisten.alias,
          users_company.name as company_name,
          produkte.id as produkte_id,
          produkte.name as produkte_name,
          sliderpic,
          produktlisten.description as description,
           MATCH (produktlisten.name,
                  produktlisten.description,
                  produktlisten.tags) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>' )
          + MATCH (users_company.name,
                   users_company.description) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>' )
          + MATCH (produkte.name,
                   produkte.description,
                   produkte.tags) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>' ) AS relevanz
     FROM produktlisten
LEFT JOIN produkte ON produktlisten.id = produkte.produktlisten_id
      AND produkte.active = 1
LEFT JOIN stilrichtung ON produktlisten.stil_id = stilrichtung.id
LEFT JOIN users_company ON produktlisten.company_id = users_company.id
    WHERE produktlisten.active =  '1'
      AND (MATCH (produktlisten.name,
                  produktlisten.description,
                  produktlisten.tags) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>')
           OR MATCH (produkte.name,
                     produkte.description,
                     produkte.tags) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>')
           OR MATCH (users_company.name,
                     users_company.description) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>' ))
 GROUP BY id
 ORDER BY relevanz DESC
 LIMIT 21
```

The database is huge, the tables too, 5-15 MB each.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: All those matches look like they will give you a headache. Is it possible to run separate queries and intersect the various responses in PHP?

Comment: Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for each table and EXPLAIN SELECT for the query.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  The solution I have in mind will need 5.6.  And the tables will need to be ENGINE=InnoDB; are they?

Comment: Try benchmarking the `MATCH` expressions. You can do that just by removing them entirely from the query and subtract the new result from the result you get when you include them. Also, if they are expensive, consider using just one match expression (in stead of six). I know that it is probably out of scope, but it looks like a job better suited to fit solr or elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to give you hints as I am not a MySQL person. if anything works would be good.

```
    SELECT produktlisten.id as id,
          produktlisten.name as name,
          produktlisten.alias,
          users_company.name as company_name,
          produkte.id as produkte_id,
          produkte.name as produkte_name,
          sliderpic,
          produktlisten.description as description,
           MATCH (produktlisten.name,
                  produktlisten.description,
                  produktlisten.tags) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>' )
          + MATCH (users_company.name,
                   users_company.description) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>' )
          + MATCH (produkte.name,
                   produkte.description,
                   produkte.tags) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>' ) AS relevanz
     FROM produktlisten
LEFT JOIN produkte ON produktlisten.id = produkte.produktlisten_id 
LEFT JOIN stilrichtung ON produktlisten.stil_id = stilrichtung.id
LEFT JOIN users_company ON produktlisten.company_id = users_company.id
    WHERE produktlisten.active =  '1' AND produkte.active = 1
      AND (MATCH (produktlisten.name,
                  produktlisten.description,
                  produktlisten.tags) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>')
           OR MATCH (produkte.name,
                     produkte.description,
                     produkte.tags) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>')
           OR MATCH (users_company.name,
                     users_company.description) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>' ))
 GROUP BY id
 ORDER BY relevanz DESC
 LIMIT 21
```

or if it were from SQL Server then I would try subqueries to limit the number of rows to have better performance like this.

```
               SELECT produktlisten.id as id,
          produktlisten.name as name,
          produktlisten.alias,
          users_company.name as company_name,
          produkte.id as produkte_id,
          produkte.name as produkte_name,
          sliderpic,
          produktlisten.description as description,
           MATCH (produktlisten.name,
                  produktlisten.description,
                  produktlisten.tags) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>' )
          + MATCH (users_company.name,
                   users_company.description) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>' )
          + MATCH (produkte.name,
                   produkte.description,
                   produkte.tags) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>' ) AS relevanz
     FROM  
     (
     Select * from produktlisten where active = '1'
      AND (MATCH (produktlisten.name,
                  produktlisten.description,
                  produktlisten.tags) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>')
           OR MATCH (produkte.name,
                     produkte.description,
                     produkte.tags) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>')
           OR MATCH (users_company.name,
                     users_company.description) AGAINST ('<<SEARCH TERM>>' ))    
     ) produktlisten
LEFT JOIN produkte ON produktlisten.id = produkte.produktlisten_id AND produkte.active = 1
LEFT JOIN stilrichtung ON produktlisten.stil_id = stilrichtung.id
LEFT JOIN users_company ON produktlisten.company_id = users_company.id
 GROUP BY id
 ORDER BY relevanz DESC
 LIMIT 21
```